# У работников редакции возник спор

Tags: стилистика

Здравствуйте. У нас в редакции возник спор о том, какая формулировка стилистически грамотна:
 "Яркое впечатление оставило отдыхающим участие в проекте..."
или
 "Яркое впечатление оставило у отдыхающих участие в проекте..."
 Где найти ответ не знаю. Пожалуйста, помогите - дело профессиональной чести.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение сложновато для восприятия, по-моему, из-за того, что на первом месте объект (яркое впечатление), затем предикат (оставило) и уже после субъект (участие в проекте).
Если поставить на 1-е место субъект - все становится понятнее:

*Участие в проекте оставило у отдыхающих яркое впечатление.*
Вариант "оставило (кому?) отдыхающим" -- очень сомнительный, действительно.

Или же "яркое впечатление" в роли субъекта:

*От участия в проекте у отдыхающих осталось яркое впечатление.*

Comment: В плане ответа на конкретный вопрос большой разницы между вариантами с перестановкой слов не вижу.  
А так - да, согласен, стилистически субъект тяготеет к началу фразы. Но это вообще свойство русского языка, и не только русского.

Comment: По-моему, наоборот: свойство русского языка - это свободный порядок слов. В отличие, например, от английского, где субъект всегда на первом месте. Поэтому английский гораздо проще изучать иностранцам, чем русский.

Comment: Это грамматическое свойство. А вот стилистика как раз и базируется на возможности перестановки слов для создания окрашенности. В нейтральной фразе (как у вас) существительное (субъект) тяготеет к началу.

Answer (score 0):

Не претендую на роль эксперта в этом вопросе, но с вариантом "оставить впечатления кому" не сталкивался. На вариант "у кого" есть многочисленные примеры в нацкорпусе.

*Это первое уголовное дело, с которым я столкнулся, оставило у меня горькое впечатление. [А. Д. Сахаров. Воспоминания (1983-1989)]*

Ксатати, есть ещё вариант "в ком", тоже весьма распространённый:
*Из всех удивительных вещей, которые мне пришлось увидеть в жизни, то, что происходило сейчас, оставило во мне самое незабываемое впечатление. [Владимир Войнович. Москва 2042 (1986)]*
Но он вряд ли вам подойдёт.

Comment: Согласна!!

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв.